Accessing LangChain LCEL variables from prior steps in the chain
I'm trying to hop onto the LCEL and Langserve train but I'm having a little trouble understanding a bit of the "magic" involved with accessing variables set in the pipeline's dictionary.
The variables appear to be resolvable from prompt templates. I'd like to retrieve these values in custom functions, etc. but it's not clear to me how to access them directly. Take the following contrived example which aims to return the source document as well as the answer in the response:
class ChatResponse(BaseModel):
    answer: str
    sources: List[Document]

store = FAISS.from_texts(
    ["harrison worked at kensho"], embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings()
)
retriever = store.as_retriever()
template = """Answer the question based only on the following context:
{context}

Question: {question}
"""
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)
llm = ChatOpenAI()

def format_response(answer):
    sources = [] # TODO lookup source documents (key: 'context')
    return ChatResponse(answer=answer, sources=sources)

retrieval_chain = (
        {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
        | prompt
        | llm
        | StrOutputParser()
        | RunnableLambda(format_response)
)
app = FastAPI()
add_routes(app, retrieval_chain, path="/chat", input_type=str, output_type=ChatResponse)

In format_response, I've left a TODO to lookup the source documents. I'd like to retrieve the source documents from the pipeline's context key. How would I access this key that was set from the first step of the chain?

from documentation at https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/sources/
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableParallel

def format_docs(docs):
    return "\n\n".join(doc.page_content for doc in docs)

rag_chain_from_docs = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(context=(lambda x: format_docs(x["context"])))
    | prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

rag_chain_with_source = RunnableParallel(
    {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
).assign(answer=rag_chain_from_docs)

then this:
rag_chain_with_source.invoke("where did harrison work ?")

returns:
{'context': [Document(page_content='harrison worked at kensho')],
 'question': 'where did harrison work ?',
 'answer': 'Harrison worked at Kensho.'}


I think maybe my example was overly simplified. RunnableParallel being able to return a merged dictionary definitely solves my example but it doesn't answer the larger question on how we can resolve these variables similar to how the PromptTemplates work fr more complex requirements.

I believe I got caught up think about this a little side ways. Looking at the citations example, I can see how creating multiple chains and using RunnableParallel to wire them together, you can solve some more complex requirements: https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/citations/
